# Jquery datatables destroy/re-create

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to reload a datatable via a json call.  I've using DataTables-1.10.9 and jquery-2.1.4.

I've tried paying with the .ajax API within datatable and got nowhere, so I thought I'd try this approach which I have sued in the past.

If I break when the HTML has been appended to the table, it looks OK (by this, I mean that the old data has been removed, and the new data is showing.  But when the $('#tblRemittanceList').dataTable({...}); command is issued again, it 'reloads' the old data, not the new.  If I don't use datatables, the raw table shows the correct data.

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function fncOpenRemittancesRead(pFrRem,pToRem) {

    wsUrl = "../Json/OpenRemittances.asp"   +
                    "?qryDatabase="         + encodeURIComponent(wsDatabase)    +
                    "&qryFrRemittance=" + encodeURIComponent(pFrRem)            +
                    "&qryToRemittance=" + encodeURIComponent(pToRem);

    $('body').addClass('waiting');
    $.getJSON(wsUrl, function(data) {
        fncOpenRemittancesFill(data);
        $('body').removeClass('waiting');
    });
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function fncOpenRemittancesFill(pData) {
    var wsHtml = '';

    $('#tblRemittanceList tbody').empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < pData.length; i++) {
        wsHtml += '<tr>';
        wsHtml += '<td>' + trim(pData[i].col_1) + '</td>';
        wsHtml += '<td>' + trim(pData[i].col_2) + '</td>';
        wsHtml += '<td>' + trim(pData[i].col_3) + '</td>';
        wsHtml += '<td>' + fncFormatDate(pData[i].col_4,4) + '</td>';
        wsHtml += '<td>' + fncFormatNumber(pData[i].col_5,2,"N") + '</td>';
        wsHtml += '<td>' + trim(pData[i].col_6) + '</td>';
        wsHtml += '<td>' + fncFormatNumber(pData[i].col_7,2,"N") + '</td>';
        wsHtml += '<td>' + trim(pData[i].col_8) + '</td>';
        wsHtml += '</tr>';
    }

    $('#tblRemittanceList > tbody:last').append(wsHtml);

    $('#tblRemittanceList').dataTable({
          "autoWidth":false
        , "destroy":true
        , "info":false
        , "JQueryUI":true
        , "ordering":true
        , "paging":false
        , "scrollY":"500px"
        , "scrollCollapse":true
    });

}
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

#### CAUSE

When DataTables destroys the table because of the option `destroy:true` it restores original content and discards the content that you've generated.

#### SOLUTION #1

Remove `destroy:true` option and destroy the table before you manipulate the table with [`destroy()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy%28%29) API method.

```js
if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tblRemittanceList') ) {
  $('#tblRemittanceList').DataTable().destroy();
}

$('#tblRemittanceList tbody').empty();

// ... skipped ...

$('#tblRemittanceList').dataTable({
      "autoWidth":false, 
      "info":false, 
      "JQueryUI":true, 
      "ordering":true, 
      "paging":false, 
      "scrollY":"500px", 
      "scrollCollapse":true
});
```

#### SOLUTION #2

Remove `destroy:true` option and instead of destroying and recreating the table use [`clear()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/clear%28%29) to clear the table content, [`rows.add()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add%28%29) to add the table data and then [`draw()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) to re-draw the table.

In this case you would need to initialize DataTables once on page initialization.

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks for your help.  I used the clear(), rows.add() and then draw() methods, as this will be more efficient I guess.

Comment: I know it's old but anyone could explain to me that `$.fn` ? It worked, although it gives me sometimes "unable to read property 'style' of undefined'

Comment: Solution 2 is working for me, and it's very easy to use

Answer (score 15):

You can initialize your datatables using the retrieve option like this:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        retrieve: true, ...
```

Than you have to clear and destroy it:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable().clear().destroy();
```

By the last you recreate your datatables:

```
 var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        retrieve: true,
```

Check the Retrieve tutorial here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve

Comment: this is perfect

Comment: I will tell you that this did not work for me and I could not understand why. So, I put a breakpoint on the line where the table was supposed to be getting re-created, using the same settings object as the first create but with the .data property updated. Well, here's what's happening. DataTables is creating a new property called aaData that has the original set of data! This is what is used to recreate the table. Grrr! Once I set aaData to equal my latest set of data, problem solved. This ridiculous, undocumented approach cost me (my customer) 8 hours.

Answer (score 4):

just use destroy() method to destory the table like this:

```
$('#experience-table').DataTable().destroy();
```

and re-initialise it like this example:

```
var table= $('#experience-table').DataTable({
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    ajax: '{{url('employee/experience/list/experience')}}'+'/'+emp_id,
                    columns: [
                        { data: 'emp_no', name: 'emp_no' },
                        { data: 'position', name: 'position' },
                        { data: 'organization', name: 'organization' },
                        { data: 'duration', name: 'duration' },
                        { data: 'action', name: 'action' },
                    ],
                    searching: false


                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datatable refresh
$('#Clienttbl').dataTable().fnClearTable();
```

Comment: `fnClearTable()` is not a function, and `.dataTable()` should be `.DataTable()`, regardless. Perhaps you were confused with another library?

Comment: dataTable() is legacy library for DataTable().

Comment: @Volomike I think you are confused. OP used `.dataTable()`, which has a function called `fnClearTable()`. It's the legacy naming for DataTable() and they can be used together in many, but not all, ways